# How to create new category for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have create a custom post type named "jobs", and I want to create a set of category for that, ie like "PHP Jobs", "Python Jobs" etc.

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 2,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', "category"),
    'menu_icon' => WJ_PLUGIN_URL .'/images/admin_menu_icons.png',
  );

register_post_type('jobs', $args);
```

But this is nt listing that category or I can't assign a new post to that category. 
While `$post = wp_insert_post( $post, false );`

I tried this also.

```
$args = array(
..
..
..
'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', "job_category"),

 register_taxonomy( 'job_category', 'jobs', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Jobs Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
```

No effect.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a taxonomy called Job Types and your terms would be PHP Jobs etc.

In your register post type function change:

`'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', "category"),`
to

`'taxonomies' => array('job_types'),`

```
add_action('init' , 'c3m_job_taxonomis' );
function c3m_job_taxonomies()
  {
     $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Job Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Job Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Job Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Job Types' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Job Types' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Job Type:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Job Type' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Job Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Job Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Job Type' ),
  );    

  register_taxonomy('job_type',array('jobs'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
     'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'job-types', 'with_front' => false),
  ));   

}
```